# Persistent Crashes on Suspend

Tags: fedora, gnome-shell, crash

I am running Fedora 27 with GNOME.
I have been experiencing crashes that occur every time I suspend the computer (when I close my laptop).
When I open it, I am logged out, and when I log in again, it tells me that either gnome-shell or XWayland crashes with SIGSEGV
I tried reinstalling the OS, and made sure to have 12G of swap memory (8GB RAM)
This did not help. I have also updated all packages.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is happening to a lot of people. This is the bug in the Fedora bugzilla:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1540102 And this is the upstream bug:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/17

Answer (score 0):

This is a specific issue with your set-up. Try disabling any gnome-extensions, scripts or tweaks you've made that are affecting gnome and by the process of elimination discover the problematic element.

When troubleshooting issues like this, make sure to search the internet around. I was experiencing the same issue, and not coming upon many relevant results and reports when searching made me realise it's most probably something with my specific setup.

I remembered that I installed  a bunch of gnome-extensions recently and tried disabling them all together. That fixed the crashes. Then by the process of elimination, I discovered that it was the "Forex indicator" extension in particular. Upon removing it, my PC was suspending normally without a gnome-shell crash.

It also might be a custom script if you added any, or any other tweaks you've made to gnome.